# Why is npm not installing react from package.json?

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-native, dependencies, package.json

If I remove my node_modules and do a clean npm install in my ReactNative project, I get the warning "react-native@0.37.0 requires a peer of react@~15.3.1 but none was installed." However, I have react listed as a dependency in the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "1.1.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },  
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.2",
    "moment": "^2.16.0",
    "react": "^15.3.1",
    "react-native": "^0.37.0",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.2.6",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-spacer": "^0.3.0",
    "react-native-material-design": "^0.3.7",
    "react-native-modal-picker": "0.0.16",
    "react-native-modalbox": "^1.3.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-viewpager": "^0.2.13",
    "rebound": "0.0.13"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `react` dependency version is `^15.3.1`. The caret character `^` in semver allows any version within the minor range for version major.minor.patch. NPM currently resolves this to `15.4.2`.

The `react` peer dependency in React Native, on the other hand, is `~15.3.1`. The tilde character `~` only allows variation within the patch version, so it's not compatible with `15.4.2`.

Define your react dependency as `~15.3.1`, and you'll get the right version.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks a mint.